# How to specify font text to 10 points instead of 10 pixels in raphael.js?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I created a graphic using paper.image in raphael js and there is a text underneath that graphic, The text currectly has `attr({ "font-family": "Verdana", "font-size": '10pt' });`
But when I look at my page source where this graphic is dislpayed, it still shows as 10px instead of 10 points . How Do i make to point to 10 points ?

Comment: I don't think you can. Use an approximation of 13px. Maybe someone will know otherwise.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to write an answer, I used 13px for 10 points , that comes with the conversion (1px = 0.75pt). I also found that we can only use font-size in pixels in raphael js. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I forgot to write an answer, I used 13px for 10 points , that comes with the conversion (1px = 0.75pt). I also found that we can only use font-size in pixels in raphael js. It solved my problem.